# Can't install Wine-Staging on new 19.04 install

Tags: apt, wine, dependencies

So I just did a fresh install on my laptop of Ubuntu 19.04 (just minimal install, nothing special). I followed the commands on WineHQ's website as I normally do, but now I am getting an error stating

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-staging : Depends: wine-staging (= 4.13~disco)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Is there something going on with Wine right now that it can't install on 19.04 or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Have you tried to fix the broken packages by `sudo apt install -f`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) and [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/q/223237/)

Answer (score 3):

To give you a reputable source to download `libfaudio0` from:

https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_19.04/amd64/libfaudio0_19.08-0~disco_amd64.deb

https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_19.04/i386/libfaudio0_19.08-0~disco_i386.deb

Then

```
sudo dpkg -i libfaudio0_19.08-0~disco_amd64.deb libfaudio0_19.08-0~disco_i386.deb
```

After that, it worked for me.

Comment: Not sure why suse has deb packages in their repo, but nice find.

Comment: Thanks, I just found the links on some Linux forum when I was googling the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've gone down the dependency chain rabbit-hole a bit and found that there is a required dependency, "libfaudio0", that does not seem to be directly supplied (currently) either by Ubuntu or WineHQ.

You will likely have to manually find the *.deb (don't forget for both amd64 and i386 if you have 32-bit enabled) from a reputable source and install it before the broken package situation can be resolved.